# Why am I getting connection reset error in Sqoop?

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, sqoop

I am using Sqoop 1.4.6v and hadoop-2.7.1v.

I am importing data from Oracle DB and using ojdbc6.jar.

It is working fine but sometimes I am getting following error:-

```
19/03/15 16:27:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1552649108375_0013_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the efforts you have done .Helping would be much easier that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something for you let me know if it helps :

This problem occurs primarily due to the lack of a fast random number generation device on the host where the map tasks execute
Please refer the sqoop guide for detailed explanation:
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_oracle_connection_reset_errors